# .dll error on boost compiled app

Tags: boost, dll, compilation

simple app, just learning to setup my boost environment...

program compiles, but I get a libboost_thread-mgw44-mt-1_51.dll is missing error

on a sidenote, I had to change thread1.stop() to t1.stop() as boost said there was no function for stop().

I have the dll, placing the dll in the same folder as the app doesn't do anything.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Threadable
{
  public:

    void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    int run()
    {
        running = true;
        while(running)
        {
            //Do Something Meaningful
        }
        return 0;
    }


  private:
    bool running;
};

int main()
{
  Threadable t1, t2;
  boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&Threadable::run, t1));
  boost::thread thread2(boost::bind(&Threadable::run, t2));

  // Let the threads run for half a second
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));

  // Signal them to stop

  t1.stop();
  t2.stop();
  //thread1.stop();
  //thread2.stop();

  // Wait for them to gracefully exit
  thread1.join();
  thread2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need libboost_thread-mgw44-mt-1_51.dll on your path - do you have that file anywhere from te boost build?

Comment: yes. i mentioned i placed the requested dll in the app path

Comment: i also added the lib to me system path env vat